# How to get value error of datetime in python for an if statement

Tags: python, django

I'm currently making an appointment app as a hobby and working on a portion of my app where when a user clicks on a day it returns all appointments they have for that day.

I'm using datetime in the django filter and noticed a small bug.

```
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

Pretty much my code in brief looks like this:

```
dateArr = selected_date.split('-')
startDate = datetime.datetime(int(dateArr[0]), int(dateArr[1]), int(dateArr[2]), 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
endDate = datetime.datetime(int(dateArr[0]), int(dateArr[1]), int(dateArr[2]) + 1, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```

I know I could write a helper function that checks to see if it's the last day of a month and then also add 1 to the month, or reset month to 1 if its dec 31.

But is there a way to get the value code for datetime errors to use in an if statement?

I looked through the docs but don't see anything. maybe value codes are a python thing and I should be looking somewhere else?

thanks in advance!

EDIT***

Think i found the answer to my own question here - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html - for anyone from the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use try and except

```
try:
  print(x)
except:
  print("An exception occurred")
```

Let me know how are you dealing with Datetime and what is your expected output.
I have done the similar.